# financially weathering

Tags: meaning

I am wondering the meaning of the "financially weathering".

The example sentence I have seen is
http://loe.org/shows/shows.html?programID=12-P13-00027

> Also, financially weathering a weatherization makeover.

If we say the above sentence with other others, how can we say?

Comment: The guy was going to *weatherize* his house, which is some kind of modification to make the house better defended against inclement weather, eg by improving the insulation. That process - the weatherizarion - was a financial disaster. It was supposed to save him money (eg in heating costs) but ended up costing him more (eg in the installation of aluminum siding) than he saved. Nevertheless, he *weathered* that disaster. Meaning he survived it. Just as you can *weather* a bad storm by hunkering down and staying dry and warm. So he *weathered* (survived) a *weatherization* (house upgrade) prob.

Comment: *Also, financially weathering a weatherization makeover.* I don't think anybody who makes a living by writing professionally for an audience would every construct such a sentence. I could be wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is derived from the phrase "to weather a/the storm"

To weather a storm is to get though it as best you can, and make it through to the other side.

This metaphor can then get extended into "to weather the financial storm".

At which point, it seems, it has been mutated into "financially weathering".

The second "weatherization" in the example sentence is to do with *weatherisation of homes*.  That is, cutting down on the energy usage of a dwelling using various energy conservation measures by fitting: insulation; draught-exclusion; double-glazing; energy-efficient lighting; etc.

In addition to energy-conservation measures, it seems the use is being extended  to domestic energy generation measures, and other things which are not weather-related.

To the sentence means:

*Surviving the cost-pressures of upgrading your home's energy-conservation measures.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is crystal clear to me.